# How to write in python numpy: b = sum(v) - a as an implicitly elementwise (vector) computation?

Tags: python, vector, numpy

I'll start with a statement of the problem.  Afterward I will demonstrate a brief sequence of coding which progressively builds the solution until the problem is reached. Obviously, here the goal is to compute b. I am asking how to do it most efficiently, ideally using an elementwise numpy vector expression, with no iterations nor loops at all:

```
b = sum(v)-a
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1251, in sum
return _wrapit(a, 'sum', axis, dtype, out)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 37, in _wrapit
result = getattr(asarray(obj),method)(*args, **kwds)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 230, in asarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Here is my best version of the code I tried to do which led up to that error. I added some print statements for clarity:

```
a = array([0,1,0,1,1])
b = +a
print b
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1])

b = array([sum(a[0:2]), sum(a[0:3]), sum(a[1:4]), sum(a[2:5]), sum(a[3:5])])
print b
array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2])

b = array([sum(a[0:2])-a[0], sum(a[0:3])-a[1], sum(a[1:4])-a[2], sum(a[2:5])-a[3], sum(a[3:5])-a[4]])
print b
array([1, 0, 2, 1, 1])

v = [a[0:2], a[0:3], a[1:4], a[2:5], a[3:5]]
print v
[array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 0]), array([1, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 1]), array([1, 1])]
```

Notice that v is a view list. The views are referring to backing array a.

```
print a
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1])

a[0]=9
print v
[array([9, 1]), array([9, 1, 0]), array([1, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 1]), array([1, 1])]

a[0]=0
print v
[array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 0]), array([1, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 1]), array([1, 1])]
```

So far so good: Variable v is a true view, meaning v is updated when a is updated.

```
b = array([sum(v[0])-a[0], sum(v[1])-a[1], sum(v[2])-a[2], sum(v[3])-a[3], sum(v[4])-a[4]])
print b
array([1, 0, 2, 1, 1])
```

Excellent, so far so good. Now lets simplify the line of code a little further.... Please notice that variables b, v, and a, all have the same number of elements.

```
b = sum(v)-a
Traceback (most recent call last)...(error messages)...
```

Oh-oh, bad code!  Now, I also tried other ways to express b, but they were similarly errors, and there is no need for me to show much more bad code here. The question is how to express the assignment expression correctly, yet most efficiently.  Especially helpful for computation if it is possible in this particular application, would be to completely avoid looping expressions and avoid list comprehensions, after the views have been set up.

It's OK in this application to set up the views using slow loops. The views wont be changing very often. The backing array a will be changing often, and will be quite large.

Thank you for reading and any of your best proposals!

Answer (score 2):

For the particular view `v` you posted, the computation can be expressed as a [convolution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html#numpy-convolve) with the kernel `[1, 1, 1]`:

```
In [78]: import numpy as np    

In [80]: a = np.array([0,1,0,1,1])

In [81]: b = np.convolve(a, [1,1,1], 'same') - a

In [82]: b
Out[82]: array([1, 0, 2, 1, 1])
```

You didn't say how your `v` changes with time, but perhaps if they are similar, you can continue expressing the computation as a convolution with changes to the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
numpy.vectorize(sum)(v) - a
```

For example:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([0,1,0,1,1])
>>> v = [a[0:2], a[0:3], a[1:4], a[2:5], a[3:5]]
>>> numpy.vectorize(sum)(v) - a
array([1, 0, 2, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11956632/577088)'s answer is the right one. But just for the sake of diversity, here's an approach that uses a rolling window over a base array, of which `a` is also a view. This assumes we know the length of `a` in advance.

First we create an overallocated array:

```
>>> datalen = 5
>>> base = numpy.zeros(datalen + 2, dtype='i8')
```

Then we define `a` as a truncated view of that array and initialize it:

```
>>> a = base[1:-1]
>>> a[:] = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Now we use `stride_tricks`. The normal strides for an array of shape `(5, 3)` and `dtype='i8'` would be `(24, 8)`; by reducing `24` to `8`, we ensure that the starting point of each row moves forward by one item instead of 3.

```
>>> window = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(base, shape=(5, 3), 
                                                      strides=(8, 8))
>>> window
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

Now we can call `sum(axis=1)`:

```
>>> window.sum(axis=1) - a
array([1, 0, 2, 1, 1])
```

`a` and `window` point to the same memory, so updates work correctly:

```
>>> a[0] = 9
>>> window
array([[0, 9, 1],
       [9, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
>>> window.sum(axis=1) - a
array([1, 9, 2, 1, 1])
```

I'll also point out that for the *particular* example you offer here, something as simple as this works:

```
>>> base[:5] + base[-5:]
array([1, 9, 2, 1, 1])
>>> a[0] = 0
>>> base[:5] + base[-5:]
array([1, 0, 2, 1, 1])
```

But I guess your actual needs are more complex.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
b = [sum(i) for i in v] - a
```

(which works because `v` as the same number of items as `a`, and that they're both 1D) ?